# Updating matplotlib graph embedded in PyQt5

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyqt5

I have a `FigureCanvasQTAgg` in which I plot a graph. That is then embedded into a `QVBoxLayout` and works really well. All functionality provided by the class I draw my graph in is there, with the exception that whenever I draw a new graph in the same window, the old one is still visible underneath, like so:

[image]

I tried in any number of ways to clear the figure before replotting but the result is the same. Below I have provided the code for the class(with a few unrelated methods removed), as in the main window I simply create an instance of this class `self.pieGraph = DrawSpent(path)`.

```
class DrawSpent(FigureCanvas):
    def __init__(self, path=''):
        self.figure = Figure()
        self.drawFigure = self.figure.subplots()
        self.annotate = self.drawFigure.annotate("", xy=(0, 0), xytext=(-20, 20), textcoords="offset points",
                                                 color='#f4b41a',
                                                 bbox=dict(boxstyle="round", fc="#143d59", ec="#28559a", lw=2),
                                                 arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle="->"))
        self.annotate.set_visible(False)
        FigureCanvas.__init__(self, self.figure)
        FigureCanvas.setSizePolicy(self, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        FigureCanvas.updateGeometry(self)
        self.SetFigureAspect()
        self.DrawGraph(path)


    def SetFigureAspect(self):
        self.figure.tight_layout()
        self.figure.set_facecolor('#acc2d9')
        self.figure.subplots_adjust(left=0, bottom=0, right=1, top=1, wspace=0, hspace=0)


    def OpenFile(self, filePath):
        with open(filePath) as graphData:
            graphDict = json.load(graphData)
        return graphDict


    def DrawGraph(self, path, file="skip"):
        if file == "skip":
            path = os.path.join(path, 'Spent\\daily.json')
        else:
            path = os.path.join(path, f'Spent\\{file}.json')

        days, amounts = zip(*self.OpenFile(path).items())
        self.containedData = self.OpenFile(path)
        self.wedges, _ = self.drawFigure.pie(amounts, labels=days, textprops={'visible': False},
                                             colors=pyp.get_cmap('plasma', len(days)).colors)
        self.drawFigure.axis('equal')
        # pyp.show()


    def UpdateNewPlot(self, path): # I tried using this method so I can clear the figure before replotting
        self.figure.canvas.flush_events() # I tried .clf(), .cla() and everything I found online
        self.DrawGraph(path)
```

Sorry if this method is not enough code but I figured there would be too much code if I were to also include a main window as my project is getting quite large.

Answer (score 0):

In case you still struggle with this, I just had the same problem and solved it calling `clear()` on the `Figure()` instance to delete the whole graph before replotting again. I.e., something like this should work:

Edit:

```
    def UpdateNewPlot(self, path):
        self.figure.clear()
        self.plot(<your arguments>)
        
    def plot(self, <your parameters>):
        self.drawFigure = self.figure.subplots()
        self.annotate = self.drawFigure.annotate("", xy=(0, 0), xytext=(-20, 20), textcoords="offset points",
                                                 color='#f4b41a',
                                                 bbox=dict(boxstyle="round", fc="#143d59", ec="#28559a", lw=2),
                                                 arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle="->"))
        self.annotate.set_visible(False)
        FigureCanvas.__init__(self, self.figure)
        FigureCanvas.setSizePolicy(self, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        FigureCanvas.updateGeometry(self)
        self.SetFigureAspect()
        self.DrawGraph(path)
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work neither by clearing `self.figure` nor `self.drawFigure`

Comment: Check if the order in which you call `UpdateNewPlot` is correct. In the snippet you shared it's not present anywhere

Comment: I have mistakenly removed that part. Unfortunately, it still doesn't work.

Comment: Ok, your `DrawGraph()` function doesn't really draw anything as is. You are plotting in `__init__`. Make a different method containing that code (see edit) and invoke it in your `__init__` and `UpdateNewPlot` methods.